# PHP read xml and show particular value

Tags: php, xml

I want to have a PHP script that reads a .xml file and shows a certain value for something. So for example I want to find out what the "name" value is for classname "Jack-User2". and I want it to show "Jack". Or if I want to show the last name for classname of "John-User1" it would show "Henry".

I've tried to search this up already, and have had not much luck with finding something that I need. I've found ones which you sent the number of order. But I want to be able to set a particular value and for it to find.

So roughly what I want is something like this:

```
<?php
$classname = "John-User1";
$xml = simplexml_load_file('myfile.xml');

echo $name; //I want the name that is for John-User1 to appear here
echo $lastname; //I want the last name here.
?>
```

My XML file:

```
<customerdata>
    <infotype>
        <usertype id="1" classname="John-User1">
            <revision_id>1223</revision_id>
            <firstname>John</name>
            <lastname>Henry</lastname>
        </usertype>
        <usertype id="2" classname="Jack-User2">
            <revision_id>1223</revision_id>
            <name>Jack</name>
            <lastname>Thompson</lastname>
        </usertype>
        <usertype id="3" classname="Brad-User3">
            <revision_id>1223</revision_id>
            <name>Brad</name>
            <lastname>Henry</lastname>
        </usertype>
        <usertype id="4" classname="Jane-User4">
            <revision_id>1223</revision_id>
            <name>Jane</name>
            <lastname>Harrison</lastname>
        </usertype>
    </infotype>
</customdata>
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help with this small project. Thanks

Comment: what value are you getting in $xml varibale . you must get array in $xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 errors in your XML file

`<firstname>John</name>` to `<name>John</name>`

and `</customdata>` to `</customerdata>`

The code bellow should work for you.

```
$classname = "John-User1";

//Read the XML file
$xmlContent = file_get_contents("txt.xml");

//Convert XML file to an object
$xmlObjects = simplexml_load_string($xmlContent);

//Create variables
$name;
$lastname;

foreach ($xmlObjects->infotype->usertype as $user) {
    //Check if names are equal
    if ($user["classname"] == $classname) {
        $name = $user->name;
        $lastname = $user->lastname;
    }
}

echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $lastname;
```

Output:

```
John
Henry
```

Comment: For future reference, how would I get it to show all of the names and last names from everything in the xml file instead of just the chosen classname. Thank you

Comment: Awesome, if you want, you can mark my answer as accpeted, so other people can see the solution.

Comment: You can make arrays `$names` and `$lastnames` and in each iteration of the loop assign the current name/lastname to it. `$names[] = $user->name;`

Comment: Hi, thank you. I've marked your answer as accepted. Just one more thing. For the  <usertype id="1" classname="John-User1">, I'm getting the data by the classname="", so I can find out name and stuff, but using your code, how can I get the id inside that also. Thank you again

Comment: Not sure, if you're talking about the attribute `id` or the value `revision_id`. In case for `revision_id`, simply do the same as above, add another variable and assign the value to it by `$revision_id = $user->revision_id;`. If you mean `id`, you can access that value by using `$id = $user["id"];`

Comment: Hi, i was talking about the id attribute next to the "classname". I tried to use $id = $user["id"];, although that seems to want to give me the id for the last set of data. So for example it'd give me "4" since the last data for id is "4"

Comment: Is the assingment in the 'if statement'? If not, it will be overwritten each time. If you want all id's, you will have to make an array

Comment: Thank you very much, I ended up just checking this and indeed I did have it outside of the if statement. But I added it to it, and it was working. Thank you again